# How to read data from file to create objects?

Tags: java, file

I'm struggling to figure out how to read the data from a file we've been given and use that to create an instance of an object. We are given a txt file of customer data for a store. It is in the following format:
123.64382392   12    1.1234123419

Each line of the file is like this. The first column is Arrival time, the second is number of items, and the third is the time it takes the customer to find one item. There are about 100 customers in this file and I'm not sure how to read from the file to create all the instances necessary.

```html
  public static void loadCustomers(){
        File file = new File("origCustomerArrivals.txt");
        try{
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            double arrivalTime = input.nextDouble();
            int numItems = input.nextInt();
            double selectionTime= input.nextDouble();
            Customer newCustomer = new Customer(arrivalTime, numItems,selectionTime);
            
            input.nextLine();
        }
        input.close();
        }
        
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("file not opened");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `String[] values = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+");` `arrivalTime = Double.parseDouble(values[0])     numItems = Integer.parseInt(values[1])    selectionTime = Double.parseDouble(values[2])` but i think your code up there would work...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static void loadCustomers(){
    File file = new File("origCustomerArrivals.txt");
    try{
    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        String[] values = scan.nextLine().split("\\s+"); 
        arrivalTime = Double.parseDouble(values[0]);
        numItems = Integer.parseInt(values[1]); 
        selectionTime = Double.parseDouble(values[2]);

        Customer newCustomer = new Customer(arrivalTime, numItems,selectionTime);
        list.add(newCustomer);
        input.nextLine();
    }
    input.close();
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("file not opened");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate on what part of your code isn't working? I tested it myself (printed out the values instead of creating a new Customer object), and it works fine. Except "input.nextLine();" in the while loop is not necessary. It will already jump to the next line, and once you reach the end of your file that will likely cause an error to be thrown.

Also, once you create the object instance, I assume you'll want to save it to a list of the objects. You can do this by creating an ArrayList of object Customer outside the loop:

```
ArrayList<Customer> Customers = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

Then as each instance is created in the loop, add it to this ArrayList:

```
Customers.add(newCustomer);
```